# PublicKeyCredential not possible to serialize

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, console.log, webauthn

I am implementing FIDO2(WebAuthn) in a Angular application.
I have gotten the PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions object and seccessfullt register.
But after calling

```
let response = await navigator.credentials.create({'publicKey': myPublicKeyCredentialCreationOption })
```

I try to send the response to the server.. But this fails.
When I tried to look at the object in the browser using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```

I get

```
{}
```

as output (?..) but when doing

```
console.log(response)
```

I get a object with values in the console...
How should the object get serialized to send to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PublicKeyCredential](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#iface-pkcredential) objects contains [ArrayBuffer](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-buffer-source-types) objects that cannot be serialized as JSON. You could base64 encode these values in your Angular app and decode on the server to get the same byte array back. A helper library to do exactly that for WebAuthn exists: https://github.com/github/webauthn-json

Comment: Note that this is a common pain point and the WebAuthn spec might be improved to provide this out of the box: https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1683

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example for anyone who needs it:

```
function bufferToBase64url (buffer) {
        
    // modified from https://github.com/github/webauthn-json/blob/main/src/webauthn-json/base64url.ts
    
    const byteView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    let str = "";
    for (const charCode of byteView) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    }

    // Binary string to base64
    const base64String = btoa(str);

    // Base64 to base64url
    // We assume that the base64url string is well-formed.
    const base64urlString = base64String.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(
        /\//g,
        "_",
    ).replace(/=/g, "");
    return base64urlString;
}
```

...
create publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
...

```
navigator.credentials.create({
    publicKey: publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
}).then(credential => {
    
    // credential created
    // console.log(credential); <-- check what is output to see what you need to call bufferToBase64url(credential.<...>) on down below
    
    // convert credential to json serializeable
    const serializeable = {
        authenticatorAttachment: credential.authenticatorAttachment,
        id: credential.id,
        rawId: bufferToBase64url(credential.rawId),
        response: {
            attestationObject: bufferToBase64url(credential.response.attestationObject),
            clientDataJSON: bufferToBase64url(credential.response.clientDataJSON)
        },
        type: credential.type
    };

    const serialized = JSON.stringify(serializeable);

    console.log(serialized);

}).catch(err => {
        
    // an error occurred
    console.error(err);
});
```